# Are there any ways to create persistent entity example given its class or type?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate Envers to audit entity changes and we have a lot of audited Hibernate entities in our project. So I want to write a test which for every entity did the following:
1) creates example object given its class.
2) persists that object to database using entity manager.
3) checks whether a corresponding audit record created or not.

The main problem with the first step and I am looking for ideas about how it could be implemented in a general way ?

I tried to fill main fields using reflection, but some of entities fails to be saved because of different hibernate errors - like foreign key doesn't exists or some not null field is not filled or ID should be predefined, etc.

So I would like to have something like that

```
    for (aClass in auditedClasses) {
        val example = createFilledEntityGivenItsClass(aClass)
        entityManager.persist(example)
        val pk = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(entity) // extracting primary key from entity.
        classToPKMap.put(aClass,  pk)
    }
    ....
    // using Envers to search for audit records.
    ....
```

So the hardest part is to actually implement this `createFilledEntityGivenItsClass` method.

*Use case:*
Some developer added a new entity type, marked it as `@Audited` and expects that everything is working.
He wanted to push his feature - but test fails and says to him:
"Your entity is not actually Audited for some reason. Please, investigate the issue"

Any ideas? Advice?

Answer (score 1):

Those nuances are often feature driven and trying to write a generic solution that takes into account all those very specific nuances will be problem prone if not down right impossible.  It's a given that developers introducing new entities and features to an application should be writing their own unit and integration tests and adding those to the application's test suite.

I'd suggest you instead take a step back and provide the developers with a means to verify the audit operation succeeded via a helper class with a variety of methods that abstract away the Envers things and only requires they have a basic understanding of how the audit system works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've come to almost the same conclusion and provided a default implementation which works for most of the cases and a possibility to write your own persist method.